# extract links (URLs), with nokogiri in ruby, from a href html tags?

Tags: ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I want to extract from a webpage all URLs how can I do that with nokogiri?

example:

```
<div class="heat">
   <a href='http://example.org/site/1/'>site 1</a>
   <a href='http://example.org/site/2/'>site 2</a>
   <a href='http://example.org/site/3/'>site 3</a>
</diV>
```

result should be an list:

```
l = ['http://example.org/site/1/', 'http://example.org/site/2/', 'http://example.org/site/3/'
```

Comment: Does anyone have a similar solution using regular expressions?  Is there any speed different?

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML.parse(<<-HTML_END)
<div class="heat">
   <a href='http://example.org/site/1/'>site 1</a>
   <a href='http://example.org/site/2/'>site 2</a>
   <a href='http://example.org/site/3/'>site 3</a>
</div>
<div class="wave">
   <a href='http://example.org/site/4/'>site 4</a>
   <a href='http://example.org/site/5/'>site 5</a>
   <a href='http://example.org/site/6/'>site 6</a>
</div>
HTML_END

l = doc.css('div.heat a').map { |link| link['href'] }
```

This solution finds all anchor elements using a css selector and collects their href attributes.

Comment: very nice, you saved my day thanks :)

one thing I get now all links from the site, but I only want the links inside the div with clas "heat". is this also possible?

Comment: would this example also work for any link that was in a <p> and not a live link?

Comment: @AaronMoodie: Yes, it would work for any link that is in a div with class `heat`. What is a live link?

Answer (score 9):

ok this code works perfect for me, thanks to sris

```
p doc.xpath('//div[@class="heat"]/a').map { |link| link['href'] }
```